# How draw 3d scene from svg image?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have SVG image like this:
[image]

I need to draw another image like this:
[image]

How I can make it with three.js or another javascript 3d library?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Do you want your SVG image to be displayed on a three.js scene? then, You can use the THREE.SVGLoader() Library to achieve it.

Comment: maybe looking for this? https://github.com/mattdesl/svg-mesh-3d

Answer (score -1):

You could also use Blender to convert it to a format supported by a Three.js loader like dae, obj...